# Visitor Level Custom Variable showing NO Sessions, Pageviews, etc

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site where I'm using GA and setting a visitor level custom variable, and then firing an event to set it.  Like this:

```
 _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 5, 'visitorId', 'someValue', 1]);
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'VisitorStats', 'SetCustVar', 'visitorId', 1, true]);
```

Now, everytime that visitor comes to the site, or does a pageview, the session and pageview should get put in the bucket for that custom variable - right?

But, when I look at the report in GA, I'm seeing values only for the "New Users" metric.  Nothing for "Sessions" of "Pageviews".

What could explain this behavior?  Do I need to "set" the custom variable with a _trackPageview instead of a _trackEvent?

Below image is from GA - showing the values in the custom variable and the bizarre result of 0 sessions and 0 pageviews.

[image]

**More Information Added**
To respond in the comments, some more information is needed.  The _setCustomVar and _trackEvent are actually called inside a Javascript function that is included on the site as part of an API.  The function supports sites that have multiple tracking codes, so we pass in the tracking code - and inside the function, we create a tracker for that tracking code.  Here is the code:

```
window._gaq = window._gaq || [];

(function() {

    function setTrackingVariable(webPropertyId, trackingValue) {

        _gaq.push(['tracker._setAccount', webPropertyId]);
        _gaq.push(['tracker._setCustomVar', 5, 'trackingVariable', trackingValue, 1]);
        _gaq.push(['tracker._trackEvent', 'Tracker', 'SetCustVar', 'trackingVariable', 1, true]);

    }

})();
```

Comment: What would explain this is if you are accidentally creating a new tracker before you send the event (this would start a new session without pageviews but with events). Look into your code if you are having a (second) call to _setAccount before you send the event.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I think that might be it.  I edited above to show the code that calls the _setAccount.  You can see what we are trying to do - i.e., there might be multiple trackers with different property IDs, so the function is designed to let the called pass in the property ID.  How could we achieve this flexibility and still manage to set the visitor-level custom variable?

Comment: Just to make sure, do you have any trackPageview-calls at all (_trackEvent does not record pageviews) ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff - No, just the _trackEvent.  I thought this was sufficient to "set" the visitor-level custom variable.